# Getting values of property objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

This question is trivial but I have no idea how to do it

I have this `swift` code

```
... = XYZ.auth().currentUser;
```

---

```
... = XYZ.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber;
```

I want to convert this Swift code to Objective-C code , I want to call `auth` *static* method of `XYZ` class and access the `currentUser` property

and in the second case I want also to access `phoneNumber` property of `currentUser` object

**NOTE**: I don't know Objective-C but I trying to build ReactNative Module that require from me to do this in Objective-C, currently I haven't the time to learn this language.

Comment: Most likely `[XYZ auth].currentUser.phoneNumber;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
[XYZ auth].currentUser.phoneNumber
```

The `[]` syntax is used to send a message (i.e. call a method) on an instance or a class. In this case we are calling a static method `auth` on class `XYZ` then we access with `.` the required property

Comment: Do you know the `.` syntax is a concise alternative to accessor method calls? You should really clarify it in your answer.

Comment: @giorashc Have your read my answer? Take also a look to the documentation [EncapsulatingData](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html). I'm not sure what you mean with your statement.

Comment: @LorenzoB Read your answer and now I understand your statement.. however the OP asked how to convert the given code to ObjC. The fact that you just gave does not change the correctness of the answer in this context imho

Comment: I think so since `.` and `[]` does not make any difference since at the end you are always send a message to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have a reply to it, I want to stress out that in [Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

> **Dot Syntax Is a Concise Alternative to Accessor Method Calls**

so, the following code:

```
NSString *firstName = somePerson.firstName;
somePerson.firstName = @"Johnny";
```

is equivalent to

```
NSString *firstName = [somePerson firstName]
[somePerson setFirstName:@"Johnny"]
```

So, in your code:

```
[XYZ auth].currentUser.phoneNumber
```

is equivalent to

```
[[[XYZ auth] currentUser] phoneNumber]
```

In addition to that, I would like to say that `auth` method should be renamed to something more meaningful.

My question is: why do you have a static method?

Comment: thanks for clarification , `ZYX` is actually `FIRAuth` class which is from `firebase` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth